# Are there any *hardware*-based CD/DVD drive emulation projects?

Tags: optical-drive, compact-disc, emulator

Does anyone know of anything like this? I am looking to create SD-card based alternatives for some of my old CD-drive-based gaming consoles.

Answer (score 1):

SYBA makes a Compact Flash to ATAPI device (Model#: SD-CF-IDE-A) that I used in a thin-client scenario last year and was very satisfied.  I got a few of these in storage, so I will have to experiment with this next week.  A very interesting idea.

The ATAPI standard is so old, and perhaps, simple-minded, that this device might be able to fool a console into thinking that it is actually a CD.  First thing I would try is to use dd (linux/unix tool) to copy the ISO to the card and see if it will boot from that.  If that doesn't work, then I would dig into the hardware spec for ATAPI and CD-ROMS devices and look for a simple solution such as cutting/jumpering a circuit trace.

Answer (score 0):

I am is still looking for Verilog code and external I/O bridge to implement an IDE (ATA) controller. Why? It seems that most FPGA<->ATA ide solutions are for supporting external drives, not external controllers.

What can be implemented purely in FPGA? Disk itself: consisting of access mapper/scheduler, cache, real storage access (gate to DDR/CF). Would do it one day.

What can, but still not? IDE. I still don't know a publicly available, not a private (datasheets open after buying 10.000 pcs) chip that can be used as a bridge between FPGA and IDE host. Maybe a series of optrons? But this isn't a digital I/O. Or, maybe I can get such a chip from old CD drive where logics and controller communications were separate?..

So at my task, the question is same as yours, but task is: find a FPGA-io-compatible-chip-that-does-IDE-connection-as-CD|HDD-drive-slave.

Comment: For my purposes here, it doesn't have to be "IDE" though. As I said, I am interested in using this in place of a CD (and actually, GD) drive on old gaming consoles -- Sega CD, Dreamcast, PC Engine Turbo Duo, etc.